# Using the Slice projection while preserving type information

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a type called Student with three properties:

```
| Student                |
|------------------------|
| Id: string             |
| Name: string           |
| CoursesTaken: string[] |
```

The `CoursesTaken` property holds the id's of the courses taken, in the order they were taken, so the last element in that array will be the id of the last course that a student took.

Now I want to query the collection for students who´s *last taken course* was X. And I'm guessing the `ProjectionDefinitionBuilder<Student>.Slice` is the method to use.

And I don't want to resort to BsonDocuments, because I'd like to preserve type inference throughout the whole thing, since I'm adding more filters later on. So I would like to pass in an `IAggregateFluent<Student>` and I want an `IAggregateFluent<Student>` back.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

### Update:

The reason I couldn't get Ryans example (below) to work was that I wasn't actually following it completely. This is what I found:

```cs
// This doesn't work (throws a NotSupportedException):
contacts.Aggregate()
    .Project(s => new
    {
        Fruit = s,
        LastNode = s.Path.Last()
    })
    .Match(x => x.LastNode == "avacados")
    .Project(x => x.Fruit);

// But this one works:
contacts.Aggregate()
    .Project(s => new
    {
        Id = s.Id,
        Name = s.Name,
        Path = s.Path,
        LastNode = s.Path.Last()
    })
    .Match(x => x.LastNode == "avacados")
    .Project(x => new Fruit
    {
        Path = x.Path,
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name
    });
```

Comment: Just think how you would do it naivly: get the last course is done by `student.Courses.Last()`. Now check if this equls the course-id for course `X`. Finally loop all your students and repeat. I´m not familiar with Mongo, but that´s how you would do it in most db.

Comment: Unfortunetly, that expression won't translate (the MongoDB driver will through a NotSupportedException). Much like LINQ-to-SQL, the idea here is to use an expression that the driver can translate into something that the db will understand.

Comment: So you basically want `db.getCollection("Students").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "Name" : 1.0, 
                "Stuff" : {
                    "$slice" : [
                        {
                            "$reverseArray" : "$CoursesTaken"
                        }, 
                        0.0, 
                        1.0
                    ]
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "Stuff" : "X"
            }
        }
    ]`, but I don't know how to do it neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to work but it's not ideal due to the projections.

```cs
            var query = collection.Aggregate()
                                  .Project(s => new
                                  {
                                      s.Id,
                                      s.Name,
                                      s.CoursesTaken,
                                      lastCourse = s.CoursesTaken.Last()
                                  })
                                  .Match(x => x.lastCourse == "avacados")
                                  .Project(x => new Student
                                  {
                                      Id = x.Id,
                                      Name = x.Name,
                                      CoursesTaken = x.CoursesTaken
                                  });
```

here's a full test program

```js
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Student : Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string[] CoursesTaken { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            (new Student
            {
                Name = "Harry Potter",
                CoursesTaken = new[] { "spells", "broomsticks", "avacados" }
            }).Save();

            var query = DB.Fluent<Student>()
                          .Project(s => new
                          {
                              s.ID,
                              s.Name,
                              s.CoursesTaken,
                              lastCourse = s.CoursesTaken.Last()
                          })
                          .Match(x => x.lastCourse == "avacados")
                          .Project(x => new Student
                          {
                              ID = x.ID,
                              Name = x.Name,
                              CoursesTaken = x.CoursesTaken
                          })
                          .ToList();            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did that actually work for you? I've also tried with .Last() within a projection expression, but I got a NotSupportedException.

Comment: I should add that I'm running this in a Linux container, and I've seen the mongodb c# driver behave differently compared to Windows in other cases.

Comment: @JohnKnoop yes it works perfectly fine. at least on windows. are you running the latest version of the driver? even the [driver's c# docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/reference/driver/expressions/#arrayelemat) show that it's supported.

Comment: I'm using version 2.9.2 so it should be new enough. I think I'll have to post a bug report at their Jira. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found the problem. I'll append it to my initial question.